# Two-level 'for' loop of a customised list

Tags: shell, for-loop, seq

Using a two-level `for` loop and `seq` works fine, and the code

```
for i in `seq 0 3`; do for j in `seq 0 3`; do echo $i $j; done; done
```

gives the expected output:

```
0 0
0 1
1 0
1 1
```

But if I want a more customised list of numbers:

```
for i in '-1 4.5'; do for j in '0 -2.2'; do echo $i $j; done; done
```

I get the output

```
-1 4.5 0 -2.2
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Remove quotes: `for i in -1 4.5; do for j in 0 -2.2; do echo $i $j; done; done`

Comment: Or, to appease the overquoters in the world, `for i in '-1' '4.5'; do ...`

Comment: It might also be educational to consider the effect of putting quotes around the backticks.  That is, surround the process substitution with quotes.  eg: `for i in "$(seq 0 3)"; do ...`  as opposed to `for i in $(seq 0 3); do ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usage of single ticks is preventing the shell from tokenizing the list supplied to the `for` loop:

```
#!/bin/sh

for i in -1 4.5
do  for j in 0 -2.2
    do  # -- keeps the highly portable printf utility from 
        # interpreting '-' as an argument 
        printf -- "$i" "$j\n" 
    done
done
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var a = [1,2,3];
var b = [1,2,3];

for (i in a) {
    for (j in b) {
        alert (i + j);
    }
}
```

I have also created a jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/f8k5tpqm/1/

Comment: How is this the accepted solution for a [tag:shell] question?